# Integrate Highcharts with Angular5 without any 3rd Party library

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, angular5

I am trying to integrate Highcharts with an Angular5 project. I know there are libraries such as `angular2-highcharts` but I am looking not to use any 3rd party and use the official highcharts.

Installed highcharts in the project using `npm install highcharts --save`.

What are the steps after to follow? I couldn't find any in the documentation.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: check this integration https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-dual-axis?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Check official [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) webpage for more details

Steps

1>Install from npm

`npm install --save highcharts`

2> In `app.component.ts` import as

```
import  Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import funnel from 'highcharts/modules/funnel';
Exporting(Highcharts);
funnel(Highcharts);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-funnel?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) demo